# Make section and article taking whole height available place

Tags: html, css

I'm getting and strange problem that I can't figure out why my section tag and article cannot take whole available height place.

Basically, I've a section and article that don't contain content, but have a div (.news) that is hidden and should be visible only when we click on UP's link.

As I understand, the article and section tags are not getting height value, and I don't understand why.

Here is the code that I'm using :

**Edit (Added the code)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sticky footer &middot; Twitter Bootstrap</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <style type="text/css">
    ​html,body{
    height:100%
}

#wrap {
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto !import;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto -60px;
    background-color:lightgray;
}

header {
    height:70px;
}

section {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}

article {
    position:relative;
    background-color:lightgreen;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}

article .news {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:red;
}

#push, .footer {
    height:60px;
}

.footer {
    padding-top:35px;
    background-color:#a3a3a3;
}
​
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="wrap">
    <header>Header</header>
    <section>
        <article>
            <div class="news row-fluid">
                <div class="span12"><a href="#" class="btn">^</a></div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="span6">My News 1</div>
                    <div class="span6">My News 2</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
    <div id="push"></div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
    Footer
</footer>
​

  </body>
</html>
```

I'm not using jsfiddle.net, because my problem doesn't appear there.

Comment: why don't you post your code here, instead of the link?

Comment: @Geo I added my code, because its long one, I didn't want to paste everything.